# Custom UITextField with overridden placeholder does not work as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have created a custom `UITextField` where I have overridden `placeholder` property. Whenever a value is written to the `placeholder` property, an `NSAttributedString` is created and assigned to `attributedPlaceholder`.

The code for the custom class is as follows-

```swift
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    override var placeholder: String? {
        get {
            return attributedPlaceholder?.string
        }
        set {
            let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.green]
            attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: newValue ?? "", attributes: attributes)
        }
    }
}
```

I created a `UITextField` in storyboard and assigned its custom class as `CustomTextField`. I set the "Placeholder" property in the storyboard to some value.

When the app is run, the placeholder is shown in gray color and not in green color as expected.

Can anyone point out why the `attributedPlaceholder` is not being shown when the app is run?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```
    extension CustomTextField {

    @IBInspectable var placeholderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return self.placeholderColor
        }
        set {
            attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder != nil ? placeholder! : "", attributes: [.foregroundColor: newValue!])
        }
    }

}
```

You can access to placeholder color via storyboard or code
Hope it will be helpful

Comment: Thanks for replying. This answer allows us to change the color of the `placeholder` using storyboard. I want an answer such that when the `placeholder` is changed using storyboard, the `attributedPlacholder` is set